# how to use this as a jquery selector to bind an event at document level

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

In jquery mobile, swipeleft event is triggered twice when binded to an element lower than document, so I have to bind swipeleft event to all objects selected by the plugin.
The following plugin would be initialized by:

```
$('#mylistview li').myPlugin();

$.fn.myPlugin = function(o){    

    return this.each(function(i, el){
        this.on("swipeleft", function ( e ) {
            ...
}
```

This code is binding the swipeleft event to each element , but it has to be done is a document level. How to use THIS as a jquery selector? The code above gives an error

```
   $.fn.myPlugin = function(o){ 
       return this.each(function(i, el){
                      //how to use "this" as a selector???
           $(document).on('swipeleft', this,  function(event){
            ...
    }
```

Comment: "is triggered twice when binded to an element lower than document" Do you are bubbling the event? In other words...are you cancelling the bubbling system?

Comment: This system does not work in this case, tried event.stopPropagation() and so on . nothing works

Comment: Anyway I don't understand why you need to listen to swipe on all the elements instead of a page (or pages).

Comment: This is what i'm trying to implement http://andymatthews.net/read/2011/02/18/adding-iphone-style-swipe-to-delete-button-to-a-listview-component-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function in this way:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(o) {
   var selector = this.selector;
   return this.each(function(i, el) {
      $(document).on('swipeleft', selector,  function(event) {
         // Code goes here
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: this.selector is returning values like this "#mentions-list li.slice(0,1)", so the selector crashes

Comment: If you're calling the plugin as you wrote, and that is using the selector #mylistview li, this can't be.